# Getting insufficient fee-payer funds whilst I try to transfer spl-token even though I have enough funds in my wallet

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, rust, transaction

**Objective:**
Transferring HNT from one account to another using rust programming language.

**account details:**

1. Both sender and receiver has more than 0.02 SOLs in their account and has enough HNTs to make the actual transaction.

**The transfer function logic i am using (Code):**

```
pub fn transfer_spl_tokens(
    from_keypair: &Keypair,
    token_mint_pubkey: &Pubkey,
    to_pubkey: &Pubkey,
    amount: u64, // Amount is now in token units
    rpc_url: &str,
    priority_fee: u64, // Additional priority fee in SOL
) -> Result<String, String> {
    let client = RpcClient::new_with_commitment(rpc_url.to_string(), CommitmentConfig::confirmed());

    let from_pubkey = from_keypair.pubkey();

    let token_program_id = spl_token::id();

    let ata_source = get_associated_token_address(
        &from_pubkey, // Owner's address
        &token_mint_pubkey,   // mint address
    );
    let ata_destination = get_associated_token_address(
        &to_pubkey,
        &token_mint_pubkey,
    );


    // Create instruction to transfer tokens
    let transfer_instruction = transfer(
        &token_program_id,
        &ata_source,
        &ata_destination,
        &from_pubkey,
        &[&from_pubkey],
        amount,
    )
    .map_err(|err| err.to_string())?;

    
    let token_transfer_message = Message::new(
        &[transfer_instruction],
        Some(&from_pubkey),
    );

    let recent_blockhash = client
        .get_latest_blockhash()


        .map_err(|err| err.to_string())?;


    // Create the transaction for token transfer
    let token_transfer_transaction = Transaction::new(&[from_keypair], token_transfer_message, recent_blockhash);

    // Send the token transfer transaction
    let _ = client
        .send_and_confirm_transaction(&token_transfer_transaction)
        .map_err(|err| err.to_string())?;

    // Create instruction to transfer SOL for priority fee
    let sol_transfer_instruction = system_instruction::transfer(
        &from_pubkey,
        &solana_sdk::system_program::id(), // Transfer SOL to the system account representing validators
        priority_fee,
    );

    // Create the message for SOL transfer
    let sol_transfer_message = Message::new(
        &[sol_transfer_instruction],
        Some(&from_pubkey),
    );


    // Create the transaction for SOL transfer
    let sol_transfer_transaction = Transaction::new(&[from_keypair], sol_transfer_message, recent_blockhash);

    // Send the SOL transfer transaction
    let signature = client
        .send_and_confirm_transaction(&sol_transfer_transaction)
        .map_err(|err| err.to_string())?;

    Ok(signature.to_string())
}
```

All the keys I provided are right, I checked them over 10 times.